# Alignment problem with subcaption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, subcaption

Is there a simple solution to alignment the subcaptions into the same level?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering          
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{kuvat/Box.ps}
            \subcaption{AOT}
            \label{fig:box}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{kuvat/box_w.ps}
            \subcaption{AOT, 1:1 Water}
            \label{fig:box_w}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering      
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{kuvat/box_3w.ps}
            \subcaption{AOT, 3:1 Water}
            \label{fig:box_3w}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Snapshots of the studied systems}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As you can see the alignment of subcaption a is not correct to compared b and c. I would like to get all horizontlly align with each other.

Comment: What is that `[H]`on `subfigure` suppose to do? (Besides, don't use `[H]` in floats, learn to use floats properly). Try `[b]` on the subfigures

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Because then I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @daleif Yes it did!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot you posted, the reason for why the caption doesn't appear below the respective graphs is that the graphs are wider than `0.3\textwidth`, the `scale=0.3` option notwithstanding.

Some suggestions:

- To fix the horizontal misalignment, replace all instances of `\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{...}` with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`;
- to fix the vertical misalignment, replace all instances of `\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}` with `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}`, i.e., add `[b]` ("bottom") placement specifiers;
- replace all instances of `\subcaption` with `\caption`;
- affix `\hfill` to the first two instances of `\end{subfigure}`;
- remove the four now-redundant `\centering` instructions; and, last but not least,
- get rid of all `[H]` placement specifiers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{kuvat/Box.ps}
\caption{AOT}
\label{fig:box}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{kuvat/box_w.ps}
\caption{AOT, 1:1 Water}
\label{fig:box_w}
\end{subfigure}\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{kuvat/box_3w.ps}
\caption{AOT, 3:1 Water}
\label{fig:box_3w}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Snapshots of the studied systems}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did that actually fix the OPs problem with the alignment of the captions when the images does not have the same height? It does not. Use `\begin{subfigure}[b]{...}` to get alignment on the bottom.

Comment: @daleif - Good point! I had focused my attention on the horizontal misalignment and not noticed the vertical misalignment. Per your comment, I've added a bullet point to recommend using `[b]` placement specifiers to fix the vertical alignment issue.

Comment: Hehe, and I never gave the horizontal any thought. Isn't `width=\textwidth` a little misleading here? That will not work everywhere. Isn't `width=\linewidth` better (I'm assuming subfigure actually sets `\textwidth` to the given width inside the env.

Comment: @daleif - Actually, inside `minipage` environments (and a `subfigure` is just a glorified `minipage`) both `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` get reset dynamically to the width of the `minipage`. It might be aesthetically pleasing to alternate `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` parameters, butAFAICT  it makes no difference in practice.

Comment: My point is just that it might be confusing to users. It is for example not the case inside a list. There `\linewidth` would be the correct value to use. So I'd rather teach users that `\linewidth` refers to the "current" line width where as they "should" see textwidth as the global text width (I know that is not true as you mention, it is just to give users a better mental picture of what to expect).

Comment: @daleif - I hear you. FWIW, I used to be much more punctilious than I am now about when to employ `\textwidth` and when to employ `\textwidth`. At some point, though, I gave up and began to use `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` more or less as synonyms (shame on me!) -- at least in the context of `minipage` environments (and a `subfigure` *is* a `minipage`) and `\includegraphics[width=...]{...}` directives. I will allow that `list`-type environments are a different matter.